# Определение DAO интерфейсов для агрегата

Tags: java, jdbc, ddd, dao

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:**
Имеется следующая схема БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и следующая структура классов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо разработать DAO интерфейс или интерфейсы для агрегата, корнем которого является класс Product.
Взаимодействие с БД осуществляется с помощью JDBC. ORM использовать нельзя.

**Что не получается:**
Я не могу понять, как должен выглядеть правильный DAO интерфейс/интерфейсы для описанной модели. Я придерживался следующих принципов, хотя теперь у меня нет никакой уверенности, что они правильные:

1. Для каждого класса бизнес модели свой интерфейс. (У меня получились соответствующие интерфейсы - ProductTagDao, ProductPriceDao, ProductDao и их реализации).
2. Объекты каждого типа бизнес логики могут быть загружены, сохранены или удалены из БД только через соответствующий интерфейс.
3. Интерфейсы DAO по возможности максимально "тупы" и предоставляют элементарные CRUD операции и их простые модификации.

Вот что получилось в итоге:

```
  public interface ProductTagDao {
      /**
      * Возвращает теги для выборки продуктов из всех продуктов отсортированных по имени. Выборка начинается с продукта под номером fromIndex                                                            
      * (первый продукт имеет номер 0), кол-во продуктов в выборке равно count. Теги возвращаются в виде коллекции HashMap, где ключами выступают
      * идентификаторы тегов.
      *
      * @param fromIndex - номер продукта из списка всех продуктов отсортированных по имени, с которого начинается выборка продуктов.
      * @param count - кол-во продуктов входящих в выборку из всех продуктов отсортированных по имени. 
      * 
      */
      public HashMap<Integer, ProductTag> getTagsByProductsSortedByName(
             int fromIndex, int count) throws SQLException;

      /**
      * Возвращает все теги для продукта с id равном productId. Теги возвращаются в виде коллекции HashMap, где ключами выступают идентификаторы 
      * тегов.
      *
      * @param productId - идентификатор продукта, для которого возвращаются все принадлежащие ему теги. 
      */
      public HashMap<Integer, ProductTag> getTagsByProductid(int productId) throws SQLException;

      public void add(ProductTag tag) throws SQLException;
      public void update(ProductTag tag) throws SQLException;
      public void removeById(int tagId) throws SQLException;
  }


  public interface ProductPriceDao {
      /**
      * Возвращает цены для выборки продуктов из всех продуктов отсортированных по имени. Выборка начинается с продукта под номером fromIndex                                                            
      * (первый продукт имеет номер 0), кол-во продуктов в выборке равно count. Цены возвращаются в виде коллекции HashMap, где ключами 
      * выступают идентификаторы цен.
      *
      * @param fromIndex - номер продукта из списка всех продуктов отсортированных по имени, с которого начинается выборка продуктов.
      * @param count - кол-во продуктов входящих в выборку из всех продуктов отсортированных по имени. 
      * @tags - коллекция всех тегов, которые понадобятся для всех объектов ProductPrice возвращаемых данным методом.
      */
      public HashMap<Integer, ProductPrice> getPricesByProductsSortedByName(
             int fromIndex, int count, HashMap<Integer, ProductTag> tags) throws SQLException;

      /**
      * Возвращает цены для продукта с id равном productId. Цены возвращаются в виде коллекции HashMap, где ключами 
      * выступают идентификаторы цен.
      *
      * @param productId - идентификатор продукта, для которого возвращаются все принадлежащие ему теги. 
      * @tags - коллекция всех тегов, которые понадобятся для всех объектов ProductPrice возвращаемых данным методом.
      */
      public HashMap<Integer, ProductPrice> getPricesByProductId(
             int productId, HashMap<Integer, ProductTag> tags) throws SQLException;

      public ProductPrice add(ProductPrice price) throws SQLException;
      public void update(ProductPrice price) throws SQLException;
      public void removeById(int id) throws SQLException;

      public void addTag(int productId, ProductTag tag) throws SQLException;
      public void removeTag(int productId, ProductTag tag) throws SQLException
  }


  public interface ProductDao {
      /**
      * Возвращает продукт по его идентификатору.
      *
      * @param id - идентификатор возвращаемого продукта.
      * @param prices - коллекция всех цен, которые понадобятся для возвращаемого объекта Product.
      */
      public Product getById(
            int id, HashMap<Integer, ProductPrice> prices) throws SQLException;

      /**
      * Возвращает выборку из списка всех продуктов отсортированных по имени, начиная с продукта под номером fromIndex 
      * (первый продукт имеет номер 0) в колличестве равном count.
      *
      * @param fromIndex - номер продукта из списка всех продуктов отсортированных по имени, с которого начинается выборка продуктов.
      * @param count - кол-во продуктов входящих в выборку из всех продуктов отсортированных по имени.
      * @param prices - коллекция всех цен, которые понадобятся для всех возвращаемых объектов Product.
      */
      public List<Product> getSortedByName(
            int fromIndex, int count, HashMap<Integer, ProductPrice> prices) throws SQLException;

      public Product add(Product product) throws SQLException;
      public void update(Product product) throws SQLException;
      public void removeById(int id) throws SQLException;

      public void addPrice(int productId, ProductPrice price) throws SQLException;
      public void removePrice(int productId, ProductPrice price) throws SQLException; 

      public void addTag(int productId, ProductTag tag) throws SQLException;
      public void removeTag(int productId, ProductTag tag) throws SQLException;
  }
```

Агрегат собирается в отдельном классе играющем роль сервиса:

```
public class NutritionManager {
     //какой-то код

     public Product getProductById(int id) throws Exception {
          HashMap<Integer, ProductTag> tags = productTagDao.getTagsByProductid(id);
          HashMap<Integer, ProductPrice> prices = productPriceDao.getPricesByProductId(id, tags);
          return productDao.getById(id, prices);
     }
}
```

**В чем нужна помощь:** пожалуйста, покритикуйте мое решение поставленной задачи и/или предложите свое решение.

Comment: надо было всё на Rust писать

Comment: судя по интерфейсу класса Product это будет корень агрегации и следовательно остальные сущности вероятно являются объектами значениями. Если это так то объекты значения не должны иметь своего Repository(или DOA) поэтому они будут лишними. Но лучше конечно понимать какие инварианты пытается защищать класс Product и могут ли они быть нарушены отделением ProductTag и ProductPrice. Если ничего не нарушится можно спокойно выделять как вы сделали.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста следующие моменты: "объекты значения не должны иметь своего Repository(или DOA)" - почему вы так считаете? " какие инварианты пытается защищать класс Product и могут ли они быть нарушены отделением ProductTag и ProductPrice" - какие на ваш взгляд в данном примере могут возникнуть проблемы (исходите из данных представленных в вопросе)?